# Code crashes but works when running with Valgrind, but Valgrind reports error

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, delete-operator

I have an array pool of objects that I am managing. The pool increases on demand indefinitely until program ends. When I try to resize the pool, it survives first three resize operations and then crashes on fourth when deleting the old array. The pool size is small, and the memory is not running out.

```
typedef measure* measure_ptr;

const uint32_t PoolIncrementSize = 50;

void CreatePool()
{
    if(measurePool != nullptr)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Pool has already been initialized!");
    }
    poolSize = PoolIncrementSize;
    measure_ptr* createdPool = new measure_ptr[poolSize];
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < poolSize; i++)
    {
        createdPool[i] = nullptr;
    }
    measurePool = createdPool;
}

void ResizePool()
{
    poolSize += PoolIncrementSize;
    measure_ptr* createdPool = new measure_ptr[poolSize];
    std::memcpy(createdPool, measurePool, (size_t)(poolCursorPosition * sizeof(measure_ptr)));
    delete[] measurePool;
    for(uint32_t i = poolCursorPosition; i < poolSize; i++)
    {
        createdPool[i] = nullptr;
    }
    measurePool = createdPool;
}

// When stuff gets returned to pool this happens
if(poolCursorPosition == poolSize)
    ResizePool();
```

The program crashes on 3rd resize operation (size increases from 150 -> 200) on the line where I delete the old array.

When running with Valgrind, the program does not crash and runs just fine, but Valgrind reports on every resize for the new array creation that `Address <some memory address> is 8 bytes after a block of size <correct amount of bytes> allocated` AND when I get and element from the pool and put a `nullptr` back in to the array to the position of the `poolCursorPosition`, it reports `Invalid write of size 8`.

Why does the code not work without running Valgrind? What can be done to make the Valgrind error go away?

EDIT:

Adding the code that access the pool:

```
void FillPool()
{
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < PoolIncrementSize; i++)
    {
        if(measurePool[i] == nullptr)
            measurePool[i] = new measure();
    }
    poolCursorPosition = PoolIncrementSize;
}

measure_ptr GetElementFromPool()
{
    if(poolCursorPosition == 0)
    {
        FillPool();
    }
    poolCursorPosition--;
    measure_ptr element = measurePool[poolCursorPosition];
    measurePool[poolCursorPosition] = nullptr;
    return element;
}

void ReturnElementToPool(measure_ptr element)
{
    if(poolCursorPosition == poolSize)
        ResizePool();

    measurePool[poolCursorPosition] = element;

    poolCursorPosition++;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have hit _undefined behavior_ in your code.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific. Which point of the code is undefined behaviour?

Comment: Look at the error message, that's the crash that valgrind figured out, and fix your code.

Comment: Also use unique pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @Lasse Not necessarily in that part of code you show, it could be elsewhere. With the given information it's not possible to give you a resilient answer what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you @MatthieuBrucher for the first constructive comment with the suggestion of using unique pointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code I pasted is is the only code where I modify the pool pointers. All other code is about accessing the array.

Comment: @Lasse That's still not considerable as a [MCVE] as required here though.

Comment: If Valgrind is reporting sometning, the program is not "running just fine". We use a different term for this kind of situation: "broken". It is runnning because Valgrind  changes the memory layout around, so that the crash is being avoided by pure chance.

Comment: @Lasse And even after your edit, you don't present a MCVE, leaving us to do guesswork. That's not useful and just wastes everone's time here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do no understand. Do you want me to include all the code from main() up to this point? It's all there that is using the array. There is nothing else to it.

Comment: @Lasse I want you to provide a minimal testcase that reproduces the problem you stated, including a `main()` function yes.

Comment: @Lasse BTW, it is quite probable that you find the problem yourself, when narrowing the code down to a minimal testcase. As mentioned it doesn't necessarily have to do with the code that manipulates your pool, it is well possible you have used _undefined behavior_ elsewhere, and you'll notice your code is working if you remove or comment out that part.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you. I am currently making a minimal test case.

Comment: You should add a main() as well that triggers the issue. And run in it in a debugger, address sanitizer...